# R: Skip empty elements while Vectorizing function

Tags: r, vectorization, data-cleaning

Hi I am trying to learn Vectorizing in R.

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(23)
obs_num=100
Observation=seq(1,obs_num)
Location_Type1=sample(1:2, obs_num, replace=T)
Location_Type2=sample(1:2, obs_num, replace=T) 
# The above does not lead to any errors

#Location_Type2=sample(1, obs_num, replace=T) 
##Error occurs when I use this formula instead.

low_bound = runif(obs_num,0,1)
mean = runif(obs_num,10,15)
df1= data.frame(Observation,Location_Type1,Location_Type2,mean,low_bound)

Vectorized_function=function(data){
  #Create groups
  i1= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 1 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 1
  i2= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 2 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 1
  i3= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 1 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 2
  i4= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 2 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 2
  #Draw values
  data[i1, "draw_value"] <- rtruncnorm(sum(i1),a=data[i1,'low_bound'],mean = data[i1, "mean"])
  data[i2, "draw_value"] <- rtruncnorm(sum(i2),a=data[i2,'low_bound'],mean = data[i2, "mean"])
  data[i3, "draw_value"] <- rtruncnorm(sum(i3),a=data[i3,'low_bound'],mean = data[i3, "mean"])
  data[i4, "draw_value"] <- rtruncnorm(sum(i4),a=data[i4,'low_bound'],mean = data[i4, "mean"])
  data
}

getvalue = Vectorized_function(data=df1)
```

In df1, there are two columns, Location_Type1 and Location_Type2 both of which can take value 1 or 2. The above code works when the four combinations exists.

a) Location_Type1 = 1 & Location_Type2 =1;

b) Location_Type1 = 1 & Location_Type2 =2;

c) Location_Type1 = 2 & Location_Type2 =1

d) Location_Type1 = 2 & Location_Type2 =2]

What I am trying to do is to draw from truncated normal distribution based on the above four conditions. In my actual data, this might not always happen.

To replicate this situation, suppose we change the following line in the above code,

```
Location_Type2=sample(1, obs_num, replace=T) #This implies LocatioN_Type2 is only one type
```

In this case, I get an error saying:

> Error in rtruncnorm(sum(i3), a = data[i3, "low_bound"], mean = data[i3,  : 
>     length(a) > 0 is not TRUE

I can see what is happening. Essentially, there does not exists any observations which satisfies conditions i3 and i4 (i.e. sum(i3) and sum(i4) =0). In this case, the portion for the lower bound ("a" in the code) causes an issue.

Could someone suggest how to ensure that I can handle these situations in the code. I want the vectorized function to be able to handle situations when any of the conditions are empty.

Comment: Can you wrap with `tryCatch`

Comment: Can you generate the sample data that returns an error with `set.seed` ?. I tried generating the data multiple times but the function runs for me without an error.

Comment: @RonakShah did you change Location_Type2 to Location_Type2=sample(1, obs_num, replace=T) ? Without this change the code will run without errors. I have added the seed and more explanations to the code for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Following @akrun's comment, I tweaked the function as follows:

```
Vectorized_function=function(data){
  #Create groups
  i1= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 1 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 1
  i2= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 2 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 1
  i3= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 1 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 2
  i4= data[["Location_Type1"]] == 2 & data[["Location_Type2"]] == 2
  #Draw values
  data[i1, "draw_value"] <- try(rtruncnorm(sum(i1),a=data[i1,'low_bound'],mean = data[i1, "mean"]),silent = T)
  data[i2, "draw_value"] <- try(rtruncnorm(sum(i2),a=data[i2,'low_bound'],mean = data[i2, "mean"]),silent = T)
  data[i3, "draw_value"] <- try(rtruncnorm(sum(i3),a=data[i3,'low_bound'],mean = data[i3, "mean"]),silent = T)
  data[i4, "draw_value"] <- try(rtruncnorm(sum(i4),a=data[i4,'low_bound'],mean = data[i4, "mean"]),silent = T)
  data
}
```

This seems to work as of now and can the error with missing/no observation.